# Apache Airflow: Error when running custom operator

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow for a short time now but I ran into a problem when I tried to work with my first custom operators.

When I try to run them (the error appears at all of my custom operators), I get the following error:

```
[2020-03-10 19:54:59,296] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 647, in execute
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

For reference, please also find below my systemd unit files for webserver and scheduler:

Webserver:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target 
#Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service
[Service]
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin"
Environment="AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/ubuntu/airflow"
User=ubuntu
#Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart= /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Scheduler:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target  
#Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service
[Service]
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin"
Environment="AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/ubuntu/airflow"
User=ubuntu
#Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Did anyone experience something similar or can anyone offer me some advice or help?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Silly mistake by me:

There was an additional indent in the execute part of the operator :-)

Comment: I just encountered the same error. Exactly as you describe it was caused wrong intendation of the execute method :-). Thanks a lot for figuring this out!